# Store returned variables by the Observable

Tags: variables, typescript, angular, geolocation, observable

This is my first time with TypeScript. I am referring the code present here: [Geolocation in Angular 2](https://gist.github.com/sasha7/0c32f3686eb49d44ccc8). I want to know how do I store the coordinates returned by the function. In the end it exports a variable, but I am not able to figure out how do I store it because of my lack of knowledge of TypeScript.

The comments did not help me. 
Also, what does this mean?

`export var geolocationServiceInjectables: Array<any> = [
provide(GeolocationService, { useClass: GeolocationService })];`

Answer (score 0):

The variable exported at the end is just creating a provider for the service, but since `GeolocationService` is already marked as a `@Injectable()` you can make the service available everywhere using angular DI.

On your application bootstrap use something like this:

#### main.ts

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'
import { GeolocationService } from './services/geolocation.service.ts'

// ... etc

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  GeolocationService,
  // Put any other global services or providers in this array
])
```

---

Then to use the service somewhere else:

#### some.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { GeolocationService } from './services/geolocation.service.ts'

@Component({
// ...
})
export class SomeComponent() implements OnInit {
  // Simple placing an argument of type GeolocationService
  // Angular DI will inject an instance of the service for you to use
  constructor(private geo: GeolocationService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let geoSource = this.geo.getLocation({ ... })
    geoSource.subscribe(
        () => {
            console.log('callback for receiving value')
            console.log(arguments)
        },
        () => {
            console.log('callback for handling errors')
            console.log(arguments)
        },
        () => {
            console.log('callback for completion')
            console.log(arguments)
        }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: @snoflake Thank you! I was wondering how do I SAVE the coordinates? had it been java, I would've done something like this:

`String coordinate = GeolocationService [0]`


How do I save the coordinates in TS?

Comment: @user2607744 for this you will need to understand the concept behind observables. I've updated the answer showing how you can subscribe to an observable and debug what happens. Then you modify the callbacks for your needs. Good luck mate :)

Comment: @user2607744 if you want to know more about observables, this is a good read: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#observable